# Textboxes Causing Problems in ASP.NET C# SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, nested

I am using a nested Gridview(I have 5 Nested Gridviews).
I have applied a Regular Field validator for these Gridviews.

But once I click the button, commas are generated in the textbox. Due to that whenever I click the button, all the validation get fired.

I have researched lots of articles but have not found one related to this.

Here is the image for the Gridview with the commas generated in the textbox:

[image: Image Of Error Page]

**HTML Code Part**

```
<%-- First Gridview--%>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    CssClass="gvstyling gridview_width_60" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" EmptyDataText="Record(s) Not Found!"
    DataKeyNames="locality" ShowHeader="false" OnRowDataBound="gvLocality_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="15px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="../images/plus.png" />

                <asp:Panel ID="pnlCompanyName" runat="server" Style="display: none">

                    <%-- Second Gridview --%>
                    <asp:GridView ID="gvCompanyName" ShowHeader="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" CssClass="gvstyling gridview_width_100"
                        OnRowDataBound="gvCompanyName_RowDataBound" runat="server"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No Record(s) Found!">

                        <Columns>

                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="15px">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfRetailer_Id" Value='<%# Eval("retailer_id") %>' runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfLocality" Value='<%# Eval("locality") %>' runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("retailer_id") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="../images/plus.png" />

                                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlSellOrderNo" runat="server" Style="display: none">

                                        <%-- Third Gridview --%>
                                        <asp:GridView ID="gvSellOrderNo" ShowHeader="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false"
                                            CssClass="gvstyling gridview_width_100" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gvSellOrderNo_RowDataBound"
                                            AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No Record(s) Found!">
                                            <Columns>
                                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="15px">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_SellOrderNo" Value='<%# Eval("sell_order_no") %>' runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblSellOrderNo" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("sell_order_no") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                        <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="../images/plus.png" />
                                                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlProductDetails" runat="server" Style="display: none">

                                                            <%-- fourth Gridview --%>
                                                            <asp:GridView ID="gvProductDetails" ShowHeader="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false"
                                                                CssClass="gvstyling gridview_width_100" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gvProductDetails_RowDataBound"
                                                                AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No Record(s) Found!">
                                                                <Columns>

                                                                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="15px">
                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" Value='<%# Eval("sell_order_no") %>' runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
                                                                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfProductId" Value='<%# Eval("product_id") %>' runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>
                                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblProductId" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("product_id") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>

                                                                            <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="../images/plus.png" />
                                                                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlWarehouseDetails" runat="server" Style="display: none">

                                                                                <%-- fifth Gridview--%>
                                                                                <asp:GridView ID="gvWarehouseDetails" ShowHeader="false" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false"
                                                                                    CssClass="gvstyling gridview_width_100" runat="server"
                                                                                    AutoGenerateColumns="false">

                                                                                    <Columns>
                                                                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                                <asp:Label ID="lblWarehouseId" Text='<%# Eval("c_warehouse_id") %>' Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                                                                <%# Eval("warehouse_name") %> (<%# Eval("qty") %>)
                                                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                        </asp:TemplateField>

                                                                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                                    </Columns>

                                                                                </asp:GridView>

                                                                                <%-- fifth Gridview --%>
                                                                            </asp:Panel>
                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>



                                                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <%# Eval("product_name") %> (<%# Eval("qty") %>)
                                                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                                                </Columns>
                                                            </asp:GridView>
                                                            <%-- fourth Gridview --%>
                                                        </asp:Panel>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>

                                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <%# Eval("sell_order_no") %>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                            </Columns>
                                        </asp:GridView>
                                        <%-- Third Gridview --%>
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Business Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%# Eval("business_name") %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                        </Columns>

                    </asp:GridView>
                    <%-- Second  Gridview--%>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="gv_item_bg">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblLocality" runat="server" Text=' <%# Eval("locality") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<%-- First Gridview --%>
```

**Code Behind File**

```
//Filling Shipping Company Name
private void FillShippingCompanyName()
{
    try
    {
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        cm.ds.Clear();
        cm.sp_dataset_execute("spdisplay_Shipping_Comany_Name", arr);

        ddlCompanyName.DataSource = cm.ds;
        ddlCompanyName.DataValueField = "shipping_code";
        ddlCompanyName.DataTextField = "shipping_name";
        ddlCompanyName.DataBind();
        ddlCompanyName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---- Select Shipping Company ----", "0"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrHandler.WriteError(ex.Message.ToString(), "Shipping-Order-FillShippingCompanyName()");
    }
    finally
    {
        cm.con.Close();
    }

}

private void FillLocality()
{
    try
    {
        cm.ds.Clear();
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        cm.sp_dataset_execute("spDisplay_Locality", arr);

        gvLocality.DataSource = cm.ds;
        gvLocality.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrHandler.WriteError(ex.Message.ToString(), "Shipping-Order-FillLocality()");
        cm.con.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
        cm.con.Close();
    }
}

//Locality Gridview Row Databound (Level 1 Grdview)
common cm1 = new common();
protected void gvLocality_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string Locality = gvLocality.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            GridView gvCompanyName = e.Row.FindControl("gvCompanyName") as GridView;

            cm1.ds.Clear();
            //Binding Company Gridview
            ArrayList arr1 = new ArrayList();
            arr1.Add("@locality|" + Locality + "");
            cm1.sp_dataset_execute("spDisplayCompanyName", arr1);

            gvCompanyName.DataSource = cm1.ds;
            gvCompanyName.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrHandler.WriteError(ex.Message.ToString(), "Recent_activity-gvRecentActivityOuter_RowDataBound()");
        cm1.con.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
        cm1.con.Close();
    }
}

//Comapny Name Gridview Row Databound (Level 2 Grdview)
common cm2 = new common();
protected void gvCompanyName_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string RetailerId = ((HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hfRetailer_Id")).Value;
            GridView gvSellOrderNo = e.Row.FindControl("gvSellOrderNo") as GridView;
            string Locality = ((HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hfLocality")).Value;



            cm2.ds.Clear();
            //Binding Company Gridview
            ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
            arr.Add("@retailer_id|" + RetailerId + "");
            arr.Add("@locality|" + Locality + "");
            cm2.sp_dataset_execute("spDisplay_SellOrderNo", arr);

            gvSellOrderNo.DataSource = cm2.ds;
            gvSellOrderNo.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrHandler.WriteError(ex.Message.ToString(), "Shipping-Order-Page_Load()");
        cm2.con.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
        cm2.con.Close();
    }
}

//Sell Order Gridview Row Databound (Level 3 Grdview)
common cm3 = new common();
protected void gvSellOrderNo_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string SellOrderNo = ((HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hf_SellOrderNo")).Value;
            GridView gvProductDetails = e.Row.FindControl("gvProductDetails") as GridView;

            FillProductDetails(gvProductDetails, SellOrderNo);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrHandler.WriteError(ex.Message.ToString(), "Shipping-Order-gvSellOrderNo_RowDataBound()");
        cm3.con.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
        cm3.con.Close();
    }
}

private void FillProductDetails(GridView gvProductDetails, string SellOrderNo)
{

    cm3.ds.Clear();
    //Product Details Gridview
    ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
    arr.Add("@sell_order_no|" + SellOrderNo + "");

    cm3.sp_dataset_execute("spDisplay_ProductDetails", arr);

    gvProductDetails.DataSource = cm3.ds;
    gvProductDetails.DataBind();
}

//Product Details Gridview Row Databound (Level 4 Grdview)
common cm4 = new common();
protected void gvProductDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string ProductID = ((HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hfProductId")).Value;

            string SellOrderNo = ((HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value;

            GridView gvWarehouseDetails = e.Row.FindControl("gvWarehouseDetails") as GridView;

            cm4.ds.Clear();
            //Product Details Gridview
            ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
            arr.Add("@product_id|" + ProductID + "");
            arr.Add("@sell_order_no|" + SellOrderNo + "");

            cm4.sp_dataset_execute("spDisplay_WarehouseDetails", arr);

            gvWarehouseDetails.DataSource = cm4.ds;
            gvWarehouseDetails.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrHandler.WriteError(ex.Message.ToString(), "Shipping-Order-gvProductDetails_RowDataBound()");
        cm4.con.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
        cm4.con.Close();
    }
}

//Submit Button
protected void btnSubmit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        cm.ds.Clear();
        //--Insert Query for Rs_Shipping_Order_Details
        string ShippingCode = "SHO" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

        string ShippingGroup = "SG" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        arr.Add("@shipping_code|" + ShippingCode + "");
        arr.Add("@shipping_Company_code|" + ddlCompanyName.SelectedValue + "");
        arr.Add("@is_shipping_delivered|0");
        cm.sp_execute("spInsert_Shipping_Order_Detail", arr);

        //Locality for loop
        for (int i = 0; i < gvLocality.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridView gvCompanyName = gvLocality.Rows[i].FindControl("gvCompanyName") as GridView;

            //Company for loop
            for (int j = 0; j < gvCompanyName.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                GridView gvSellOrderNo = gvCompanyName.Rows[j].FindControl("gvSellOrderNo") as GridView;

                string RetailerId = ((Label)gvCompanyName.Rows[j].FindControl("lbl")).Text;


                //Sell Order for loop
                for (int k = 0; k < gvSellOrderNo.Rows.Count; k++)
                {
                    //Product Details Gridview
                    GridView gvProductDetails = gvSellOrderNo.Rows[k].FindControl("gvProductDetails") as GridView;
                    string SO = ((Label)gvSellOrderNo.Rows[k].FindControl("lblSellOrderNo")).Text;
                    int retailer_Id = Convert.ToInt32(RetailerId);

                    //Product Details for loop
                    for (int l = 0; l < gvProductDetails.Rows.Count; l++)
                    {

                        //Warehouse Details Gridview
                        GridView gvWarehouseDetails = gvProductDetails.Rows[l].FindControl("gvWarehouseDetails") as GridView;

                        string ProductId = ((Label)gvProductDetails.Rows[l].FindControl("lblProductId")).Text;

                        //Warehouse Details for loop
                        for (int m = 0; m < gvWarehouseDetails.Rows.Count; m++)
                        {
                            TextBox txtQty = gvWarehouseDetails.Rows[m].FindControl("txtQty") as TextBox;
                            string LastValue = txtQty.Text.Split(',').Last();

                            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastValue) == false)
                            {
                                string Warehouse_Id = ((Label)gvWarehouseDetails.Rows[m].FindControl("lblWarehouseId")).Text;
                                int warehouse_id = Convert.ToInt32(Warehouse_Id);
                                string Qty = LastValue;

                                //Insert Query for Rs_Shipping_Detail_Mapping
                                ArrayList arr1 = new ArrayList();
                                arr1.Add("@shipping_order_code|" + ShippingCode + "");
                                arr1.Add("@retailer_id|" + retailer_Id + "");
                                arr1.Add("@sell_order_no|" + SO + "");
                                arr1.Add("@product_id|" + ProductId + "");
                                arr1.Add("@c_warehouse_id|" + warehouse_id + "");
                                arr1.Add("@shipping_group|" + ShippingGroup + "");
                                arr1.Add("@qty|" + Qty + "");

                                common cm1 = new common();
                                cm1.sp_execute("spInsert_Shipping_Detail_Mapping", arr1);


                                ////Generating Pdf for Each Sell Order
                                //if (m == gvWarehouseDetails.Rows.Count - 1)
                                //{
                                //    Generate_SellOrderWise_PDf(SO, ShippingCode, ShippingGroup);
                                //}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect("../final-shipping-order/?SG=" + ShippingGroup, false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrHandler.WriteError(ex.Message.ToString(), "Shipping-Order-btnSubmit_Click1()");
        cm4.con.Close();
    }
    finally
    {
        cm4.con.Close();
    }
}
```

**Question :**

**1. How do I remove the commas from the textboxes?**

**2. Reason for these commas? (Why are the commas being generated on the button click?)**

**3. Limit for the Nested Gridview ?**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Where is your code ? Please show your code, so that we can help you properly.

Comment: Remove comma's using regular expression.
string result = txtbox1.text;
result = result.replace(/[, ]+/g, " ").trim();
You need to find textbox on the server side first.

Comment: @amit Please Check the Code I have made edit to the Question

Comment: @manu I did not got you. My all validations are getting fired then How can I access the code behind file. My Question why is these comma are coming

Comment: Share your code behind file

Comment: @Coder Hawk I have posted the code Please have a look at it...!!!

Comment: @Amit Kumar Have a look at it I have Paste the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have duplicate form field `names`, the values are concatenated together with commas.

So, for example, if you have the following..

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="">
<input type="text" name="name" value="">
```

.. your resulting value on Request.Form postback looks like this:

```
name=,,
```

That's what's happening.

Here are a few possible solutions to your problem, though I have not tested any of them :)

**1) UpdatePanel**

From reading, it seems that if you create an UpdatePanel for the offending grid control (<`asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`) , it removes this problem. Again, I have not tested this

**2) Changing DataBind() behavior during `Page_Load()`**

So...

```
page_load()
{
    if(!isPostBack())
    {
        // DataBind normally
        myGridview.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        //Some intelligent way to remove commas before binding
    }
}
```

... But that doesn't change the fact that the `,,,values` are being posted in the first place. And so, if your primarily concerned with the end aesthetic and not behavior, you can just use JS to strip out the commas (as previously suggested hinted at.)

3) JS - Get Rid of the Commas:

(as suggested [here](http://aspforums.net/Threads/135070/ASPNet-Nested-GridView-with-TextBoxes---Unwanted-comma-in-TextBox-after-PostBack/))

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[src*=plus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>")
        $(this).attr("src", "images/minus.png");
        $("input", $(this).closest("tr").next()).each(function () {
            this.value = this.value.substring(',', '');
        });
    });
    $("[src*=minus]").live("click", function () {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/plus.png");
        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps :)

**[Edit] - Validation**

I would fire off validation using the .keydown() event. In your case, it might look something like this:

```
// Bind to each input with id='txtQty', in each row, in the "gridview" with id='gvWarehouseDetails'
 $("#gvWarehouseDetails tr input[id*='txtQty']").each(function () {
    $(this).keydown(function (event) { // <-- specifies the specific input
        // Validation logic goes here...
    });
});
```

Comment: I have been researching this error from last one month. Then now I have found that this is not the problem of Gridview. this is the problem of the Javascript. I have found that on page source gridview by default give all the ID as unique ID. Without that javascript of the Button Code is running as expected. So what should we have to do I donot understand I am bit new in Jquery

Comment: I have used your javascript but still issue is there

Comment: my issue is resolved but I also have to give validation for the gridview then I dont know what render first validation or javascript

Comment: I've updated my answer with how to fire off validation logic using jQuery

Answer (score 4):

The *Ajax Control Toolkit* is a viable solution, however support for it has become non-existent.  I'm assuming there is a level of *dynamic control* on that field.  In essence, the grid will display it at certain instances?

Either way, you could add a specific `class` to the field:

```
<asp:Textbox id="txtContent" runat="server" CssClass="Validator">
```

Essentially when the grid adds all of these fields to your page, they'll all have the `Validator class`.  So you can write JavaScript to actually strip the character out of the field, example:

```
$('.Validator').on('blur', function() {
     $(this).replace(',', '');
});
```

As soon as the focus changes, that field will remove the `,` from the field as soon as the mouse leaves the `,` will be removed from the field.

That is one approach, countless other options do exist as well to accomplish this.  This solution is pretty easy, agile, and light so it should be adequate.

**Update:**

---

The solution I chose shouldn't require a loop over those fields.  Simply because `blur` triggers whenever a `change` or `focus` is lost on that field.  Since you mentioned the `,` appears when the user clicks in the field.  Otherwise you could do validation on all the fields.  All you simply would need to do:

```
$('.Validator').each(function() {
     // Will iterate through each field.
});
```

So you could essentially use JavaScript yourself to validate those fields, or use a simple library such as `Valid8` which will do all client-side validation.  *No postback, all done client side before sent to the server to process.*

**Avoid:**

- Update Panel - These are quite a pain and incredibly inefficient. The way they work basically is by *taking your entire page and storing it memory* then does an Ajax request and refreshes your page and pulls all the contents out of memory to place on the page.  Additionally it makes working with the Asp.Net **Page Life Cycle** incredibly difficult.

Comment: I have been researching this error from last one month. Then now I have found that this is not the problem of Gridview. this is the problem of the Javascript. I have found that on page source gridview by default give all the ID as unique ID. Without that javascript of the Button Code is running as expected. So what should we have to do I donot understand I am bit new in Jquery

Comment: When you add the `Class` field, it will create the same identifier for all of those fields.  This will give Javascript the ability to modify the code.

Answer (score 3):

Hardik, how is `txtQty.Text` bound at first?
Does it come as an empty text box?

You using the code `string LastValue = txtQty.Text.Split(',').Last();` to try go get rid of this comma values inserted or the values bound come with commas? I mean, you using the same UI culture from values in the database and the app or do you have to format it before displaying it?

Comment: I Really did not got what you said but I Wants -- On button click how to get rid of comma which are generated in text boxes

Answer (score 3):

I Don't know what is happening in your code. But If you want to get rid of Comma (',') then I should suggest one thing to you.

Add a reference of `AjaxControlToolKit` and register it in your **aspx** page as shown below:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=[VersionNumber], Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=[TokenNumber]" %>
```

Or You can refer [How to install AJAX Control toolkit](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/)

Once you have installed AJAX Control Toolkit, Go to your page and in your grid TemplateField, below `TextBox` **txtQty**, add **`FilteredTextBoxExtender`** as shown below:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQty" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender runat="server" InvalidChars="," FilterMode="InvalidChars" TargetControlID="txtQty" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

By Adding `FilterTextBoxExtender`, It will not allow characters to be inserted which are mentioned as **InvalidChars** to the textbox 'txtQty'.

Comment: I have been researching this error from last one month. Then now I have found that this is not the problem of Gridview. this is the problem of the Javascript. I have found that on page source gridview by default give all the ID as unique ID. Without that javascript of the Button Code is running as expected. So what should we have to do I donot understand I am bit new in Jquery

Comment: what you have written in your javascript ?